# Do I need to unsubscribe BoundNodeCallbackObservable

Tags: rxjs

```
const source = Observable.bindNodeCallback(https.get)(www.google.com);

source.subscribe({
   next: ([res, body]) => {},
   error: () => {},
   complete: function () { //cannot use arrow function
     this.unsubscribe();
   }
 });
```

Is this the correct format to unsubscribe ?

Answer (score 1):

Observables created using `bindNodeCallback` will either complete or error, so you don't need an explicit unsubscribe. The subscription will be unsubscribed automatically.

However, if you do want to unsubscribe explicitly, you can; like this:

```js
const subscription = source.subscribe({
  next: ([res, body]) => {},
  error: () => {},
  complete: () => subscription.unsubscribe()
});
```

Comment: I tried on Rxjs 5, using arrow function throws an error with function of `unsubscribe` is undefined

Comment: That should not be possible unless the callback is invoked synchronously - which would not be best practice for a callback-based API. I can't look into this right now, but will have a look later.

Comment: No problem here. It works fine for me with RxJS 5.2.0.